# Why is the wmf format image extracted from docx using openxmlsdk distorted?

Tags: image, openxml

Why is the wmf format image extracted from docx using openxmlsdk distorted?

My code:

```
 Metafile metafile = new Metafile(imgpart.GetStream());
 metafile.Save(filename,ImageFormat.Wmf);
```

Orginal image vs. extracted image:

[image: Original vs Extracted Image]

Comment: It looks like you're losing data when you save it. Was the inserted image originally in WMF format? Have you tried saving with one of the other image formats?

Comment: thanks, I lost data when save it